# Get set of ID's from one table and use them to spawn a row in different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables 'users' and 'settings'. I am trying to create a new row in settings for each user in users to initialize a default setting.

```
INSERT INTO settings
    (user_id, setting_id, value)
VALUES 
    (
        (SELECT id
        FROM users),
        16,
        true
    )
```

this returns the error

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO settings (user_id, setting_id, value)
    SELECT id, 16, true
    FROM users;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax.

Add the **constant** values to `select` query *select list*

```
INSERT INTO settings
    (user_id, setting_id, value)
SELECT id,16,true
FROM users
```